# Hot to change title and description when share in facebook

Tags: jquery, html, facebook

I have no of products and want to share them in facebook with different title and description. But when i share my page, it takes data from my page meta tags.
How can i change title and description dynamically to be shared..?

Comment: Can i change the page meta data ie title and description ?

Comment: Now i am using : https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?s=100&p[title]=My%20Title&p[url]=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.mydoamin.com&p[summary]=Description&&p[images][0]=http://images.mydoamin.com/logos/mylogo.jpg                              Its working fine but image is not displaying. Why?

Answer (score 1):

The following meta tags will allow you to control what Facebook picks up:

```
<meta property="og:title" content="" />
<meta property="og:description" content="" />
<meta property="og:url" content="" />
<meta property="og:image" content="" />
<meta property="og:type" content="article" />
```

Comment: yes, i got that.But I have different title and description for products, and need to share dynamically.

Comment: If you have single product pages then the values should be simple to change, if you have multiple products per page you could either use JavaScript to change them, or use the Facebook JS API for more custom behaviour.

Comment: @TomWalters, changing the meta info per JavaScript won’t work, because the FB scraper doesn’t “speak” JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

You can read more about [Open Graph](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/).

With this tool you can see what will be your title and description:
[Linter](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug)

It's good to know, once Facebook cached your data, you can't overwrite it until it's cached again.

Maybe you can use this form:

```
<script>
var your_desc = item.desc;
</script>
<meta property="og:description" content=your_desc />
```

Comment: i am using: $("meta[property='og\\:title']").attr("content", 'xyz'); but it doesn't change content

Comment: Did you watch the HTML source of the page or the share datas in Facebook?

Comment: Because facebook caches your data, changing it like in your example won't work

Comment: Of course retroactively it will not work. This way is working if you would change the shown up OG data in the Share popup.
You can empty the Facebook cache with the Scrape Again button.